# Creating multiplots in Python from function outcomes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that creates a complex plot given a dictionary. Now I have two dictionaries, and I would like to create a multiplot. Intuition would say:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict_1={'m':1,'n':0}
dict_2={'m':5,'n':1}

def nice_plot(dict):
  x=np.linspace(-5,5)
  _,ax=plt.subplots()
  return ax.plot(x,dict['m']*x+dict['n'])

fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0]=nice_plot(dict_1)
ax[1]=nice_plot(dict_2)
fig.show()
```

But it does not work, it creates an empty multiplot with 2 columns and then plots the two lines.
Using return `plt.plot(x,dict['m']*x+dict['n'])` plots the two lines in the second axis.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, something like the following:

```
def nice_plot(dict, ax):
  x=np.linspace(-5,5)
  return ax.plot(x,dict['m']*x+dict['n'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

nice_plot(dict_1, ax[0])
nice_plot(dict_2, ax[1])
```

Output:

[image]